# Java - add data to String [ ] and Composer[ ][ ] dynamically

Tags: java, android

titles contains header items and composer are rows details for each corresponding header.  How can one add data to these objects dynamically.

String[] titles = {"Renaissance", "Baroque", "Classical", "Romantic"};

```
Composer[][] composerss = {
    {
        new Composer("Thomas Tallis", "1510-1585"),
        new Composer("Josquin Des Prez", "1440-1521"),
        new Composer("Pierre de La Rue", "1460-1518"),
    },
    {
        new Composer("Johann Sebastian Bach", "1685-1750"),
        new Composer("George Frideric Handel", "1685-1759"),
        new Composer("Antonio Vivaldi", "1678-1741"),
        new Composer("George Philipp Telemann", "1681-1767"),
    },
    {
        new Composer("Franz Joseph Haydn", "1732-1809"),
        new Composer("Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart", "1756-1791"),
        new Composer("Barbara of Portugal", "1711Ð1758"),
        new Composer("Frederick the Great", "1712Ð1786"),
        new Composer("John Stanley", "1712Ð1786"),
        new Composer("Luise Adelgunda Gottsched", "1713Ð1762"),
        new Composer("Johann Ludwig Krebs", "1713Ð1780"),
        new Composer("Carl Philipp Emanuel Bach", "1714Ð1788"),
        new Composer("Christoph Willibald Gluck", "1714Ð1787"),
        new Composer("Gottfried August Homilius", "1714Ð1785"),
    },
    {
        new Composer("Ludwig van Beethoven", "1770-1827"),
        new Composer("Fernando Sor", "1778-1839"),
        new Composer("Johann Strauss I", "1804-1849"),
    },
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't add items to an array without rebuilding/recreating it - which is what ArrayList does: it holds an array internally, and when you add items, the ArrayList recreates the array with the added items.

So in other words - you should probably check if ArrayList can be your answer.